# System.Data.SqlConnection not working

Tags: c#

When I try to use System.Data.SqlConnection, I found an error and it doesn't Work.

I tried to add "System.Data.SqlConnection.dll" to my visual studio 2017 but it also doesn't work.

Any one can help me please?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's in the `using System.Data.SqlClient;` namespace.

Comment: I think you should include "System.Data.SqlClient, since SqlConnection is located in that namespace.

Comment: It is a good trick to use `ctrl + .` for adding missing assemblies. VS will try to resolve conflicts and add the using statements if possible.

Comment: Before assuming one of the most used classes in .NET "isn't working" check for typos.

Comment: Install the nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/ and change your using to using System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Thank you very much :) the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong using statement.

try `using System.Data.SqlClient`

alternatively, if you don't know what namespace to include, try `ctrl + .` on the class name, for example here `SqlConnection`. Visual Studio will try to find the namespace and add the using statement. Doesn't always work but often helps adding needed using statements.